# How do I test Video Ads (Vungle) in an android app

Tags: android, ads, vungle-ads

I am making an application with video ads first time, but I have many doubts. Can I test those ads? If yes, how? Also, I have to execute a set of codes only after the ad is finished. How to do that? And if there is a network problem in streaming ads, will it show error automatically like "network error" or I have to define it? If yes, please tell me how

I followed the instructions, how to monetize with video ads (Vungle).

Comment: What is there to test? Also, if it's like Google ads, it won't let you test them because obviously it is like generating ad revenue for yourself

Comment: I mean, like banner test ads. Also, how do I execute a set of code only when Ad is finished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My name is Aki and I am an Integration Engineer at Vungle.
Yes. You can test our ads with "Test Mode". Our SDK will let you know when an ad is finished with successful view. Also, the SDK will let you know when an ad is ready to playback after download.

Please check our integration guide:
https://support.vungle.com/hc/en-us/articles/204222794-Get-started-with-Vungle-Android-SDK
https://support.vungle.com/hc/en-us/articles/204463100-Advanced-Settings-for-Vungle-Android-SDK

If you have any issue in integration, please send a message to tech-support@vungle.com>. We are happy to help you.

Thanks,
-aki